# Best way to store images so that they are same across formats

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

We are designing an algorithm that builds a Merkle tree from a list of Perceptual hashes. the hashes are generated for every frame that we capture from a video. The incentive behind this is that we are able to identify hashes even if the video format has changed.

To verify this, we had two images : Video.mp4 and Video.avi. We extracted frames at 30 fps, and ran pHash over these images. To test our functionality, it is imperative that both the images at every instance (from .mp4 and from .avi) stay the same. However there are still some differences in those two images.

Including code for reference:

1. Extract frames from video:

```py
def extract_frames(file_path, write_to_path, fps=30):
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)

  count = 0
  os.mkdir(f'{write_to_path}/frames')
  while cap.isOpened():

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:

        grayed_image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imwrite(f"{write_to_path}/frames/frame{count}.bmp", grayed_image)
        count += fps # i.e. at 30 fps, this advances one second
        cap.set(1, count)
    else:
        cap.release()
        break
  print(f"Frame Extraction complete. Extracted {count // fps} frames.")
  return count
```

2. Test if two images are similar

```py
def check_images(path_1, path_2):
    img_1 = cv2.imread(path_1, 0)
    img_2 = cv2.imread(path_2, 0)

    if img_1.shape == img_2.shape:
      difference = cv2.subtract(img_1, img_2)
      print(difference)
      result = not np.any(difference)
      return result
    
    print("Unequal shapes, ", img_1.shape, img_2.shape)
    return False
```

3. The Perceptual hash function

```py
def generate_p_hashes(count, frame_path, fps=30):
  count_two = 0
  hashes = []
  # fileToWrite = open('/content/hash.txt', 'a')

  while count_two != count:
    temp_hash = imagehash.phash(Image.open(f"{frame_path}/frames/frame{count_two}.bmp"))
    count_two += fps
    str_temp_hash = str(temp_hash)
    hashes.append(str_temp_hash)
  
  print(f"PHash generation complete. Generated {count_two // fps} hashes")
  return hashes
```

Imagehash is a Python package available at : https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash

4. The images:

a. Frame captured from .avi file:
[image]

b. Frame captured from .mp4 file:
[image]

Here's what I've tried:

1. Convert image to grayscale so color channels are excluded.
2. Try all different image formats (JPEG, PNG with compression 0, TIFF, BMP)

Sample output:

[image]

What is the best way to store these images, so that irrespective of the video source that I am extracting from, the image will stay the same ?

Comment: I don't understand the premise behind this. Are you assuming you will get pixel-perfect identical frames  from two videos with different compression and formats in which you repeatedly try to position 30 frames down the length of the video?

Comment: "Best way to store so that they are same across formats": this makes no sense. Storing under some format does not influence the other files !

Comment: merkle trees on perceptual hashes, that idea needs a theoretical justification. you're working with similarity/dissimilarity here, not with exact equality. whatever operation you use to combine hashes in the merkle tree has to **maintain** the dis/similarity measure. -- before you prove that, prove first that your perceptual hashes of differently encoded videos (mp4 and avi are **containers**, not codecs) still show some similarity. -- you didn't show any code that calculates perceptual hashes. do you think that isn't relevant to the question?

Comment: and what's with the magic numbers given to `cap.set`? there are named constants for that. -- further, seeking on video files... is rarely exact. don't count on that. don't seek. just read sequentially.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, I have added the relevant piece of code. Since the implementation relied on a third  party library, I did not think of putting that earlier.

Comment: have you looked at the images you seem to have trouble with? you should show us these pictures.

Comment: I have added the images as a reference

Comment: and *those* give you trouble? how? what trouble precisely? what numbers/results?

Comment: In order to check how equal these two images are, I ran the `check_images()` function. The problem as I see it, is I am looking for equality, which does not possible at the moment by just hashing images.

Comment: Check this related solution: https://www.similar.pictures/algorithm-for-perceptual-image-comparison.html. You could resize source images with high precision float values for pixels. Therefore even if image is the same, but because of different compression you will get somewhat different pixel values.

Answer (score 0):

Lossy-compressed files or video streams of different technologies will never give you exactly the same content from the same original source, this is not possible. With a high compression ratio, the images can be quite different.

If the goal is to authenticate, watermark or detect copies, you need to use features that are robust to lossy compression/decompression.

Comment: Can you please provide any link or pointers to what I should potentially be looking at ? Thanks

Comment: @ShubhankarKG: sorry, no.